# Software platform for a scalable server-solution that will serve an iOS client and a web frontend

Tags: ios, web, service, server

I'm about to start work on a project that will contain an iOS client, a server backend and eventually a web client. The service will start small, but might potentially become fairly large in terms of number of users and data transmitted.

I have very little background in server programming (other than having a longer Linux phase back in the 90s), and mostly just do frontend dev work, with my primary platform and language of choice being iOS and objc/swift. Now I'm in the position where I most likely will be hiring a full-time dev to work on the backend and web frontend, starting in January, but I honestly have no idea what software platform I should be basing the server-side stuff on, and therefor no idea what I should look for in a new hire.

What do people recommend for a server-side software platform for something that needs to be very scalable? I'm thinking we might to Amazon EC2 for the hosting, and I think it might be easier to find .NET devs here, so I'm kinda leaning towards that, but I don't want to base such a crucial decision on just what I have at hand here now.

Comment: This probably isn't the best place to ask this sort of question, the answers will be mainly opinion based. However, I'd recommend you just find a knowledgeable server developer and query him on it. There's a lot of variables that you haven't described like the types of requests you'll be making, the types of files (images, video, audio), if you'll be doing websocketing. If it needs to be a custom implemention, a server dev will help you tailor this. Otherwise, if you can get away with it, try a service like Parse, (it'll speed up your dev time by a lot)

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to use Parse after Facebook bought it. And asking a server dev usually means he'll tell you which platform he's most comfortable with. Are there any other places where this question might get more traction?

Comment: I've been in places that use PHP (horrible and slow but you can throw 100s of servers at it), Java using Play framework that was manual scaling, a few node.js (strongloop) but we didn't take off on them so no clue how it would scale. If you need reliability and stability, Java is great. If you need speed and new experimental stuff node.js. If you don't have anything else, PHP. I don't have any experience with .NET. All I know is the licensing for it adds overhead.

Comment: If i had a choice of dev I'd probably want a Java environment. There's a lot of Java devs and its a very old stable, albiet crufty and boilerplate--(ey?), environment. Node.js moves and changes very quicky, its fun but also feels like a bodge job. AWS also has a BaaS in beta called AWS Mobile Hub if you're not comfortable with Parse. I've used CloudKit (Apple) to make an app, its got a nice price (free) but the restrictions make it unsuitable for lots of ideas.

Comment: Never been a big fan of java, but that's just me. We have a ton of C#/.NET developers in Norway, but Java is probably the second most used language here. AWS Mobile Hub looks interesting.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. C#/.NET is the way to go. You can get away with less servers if you have great caching policies (this is independent of any lang/web platform.) In the end, its all about pragmatism to get a product finished not what's "ideal." If you follow the history of any mega service, they're all continually being developed for performance and usability. Sometimes changing the server architecture completely. eg. twitter changed from rails to scala/java because of performance limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<wry>`
Follow the fads! Pick the flavor of the day for every piece, that way when the fad fades it will be unsupportable and undocumented. 
`</wry>`

`<expensive style="slow:10; methodical:7; costOverrun:50%">`
Oh, wait, no... Perhaps find an expensive consultant with comfort in all the stable and long-term supportable candidates and map out the data structure and needs for performance for your app.
`</expensive>`

`<structural>`If you have table based data pick something SQLy and if you have tree based data go for something less SQLy (maybe not all the way to M but who knows...).

If you are competing with another product choose whether you are going for quick turn around feature adds, performance, stability, or some other competitive point.

Decide where you want to draw the line on how much you want to have done on the server vs client. If you invest in the server, you can get great performance and reduce platform variability. However you will need to build security in from the ground and stay on top of it. If you process on the client your performance will appear linked to the customers's investment in HW.`</structural>`

`<nextSteps>`
Your bounty is running out, and you haven't given us much info to help you pick a platform. I suggest identifying as much information as you have and decide if you can disclose enough to get help in this public forum or hire someone you can get to sign a non-disclosure agreement so that you can really dig into the architectural requirements.

Please note that http://norvig.com/21-days.html Peter Norvig (read to see why he is authoritative) quotes Alan Perlis: "A language that doesn't affect the way you think about programming, is not worth knowing". The architecture question should be answered by someone who knows enough languages and platforms to understand the way that programmers who use it think. You REALLY don't want someone who know Java and can read someone else's php to write your php. You want someone who can think in the language you choose. You want an old experienced programmer who is multilingual to review your product to help you identify the language and platform that best meets your business needs.
`</nextSteps>`

Some of this is tongue-in-cheek, but perhaps the best advice I can offer you is to hire the best person in your market and trust them.